# Changing NavigationController's Content View width without affecting the Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

Is there a way to change the width of the transitioning area **below the navigation bar**, without changing the frame of the bar itself?

In my case, i wanted the width of the **transitioning area** to not change even if it's in landscape mode, but I need the `UINavigationBar` to fill the screen width depending on the orientation.

currently, i can change the width of the whole navigation view controller
but the navigation bar also changes with it, and that's not the result i want.

EDIT:
this is a [drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88fZh.png) of what i wanted to achieve

is this possible?
thanks. :)

Comment: Explain your problem more or with images

Comment: Take a look at the guidelines on how to write a question. There's no example code or context surrounding your question, which could make it harder for people to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You want the content container the same width in both portrait and landscape? Set the width to 375. Your question is unclear.

Comment: hi, sorry bout that, i couldn't embed an image yet, but i attached a link of the drawing of what i want to achieve. hope that helps clear my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can set the fix width of your content container, so when you rotate screen content container won't change its width. Let me know if this help you out. Otherwise please attach a snapshot.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, i attached a link to my drawing in my question.
basically what i wanted to do was set a different width for the **transition area** below the navigation bar, and the **navigation bar itself**.